# android/ios opening external browser while maintaining controle

Tags: android, ios, browser, url-scheme

Good morning everyone,

I am facing an issue with both my Android and iOS apps. While they use webviews, we just had a requirement coming in to open the external browsers in order to reach our payment portal. For iOS especially, as part of the iOS guidelines this is preventing my app from getting accepted unfortunately.

I know how to open the browser externally, however I cannot close it as easily. It seems to boil down to it being a different application all together opened from either my android or iOS code. In this aspect window.close() or something similar does not work.

My question is, is there a trick to it using custom url schemes, all I am trying to achieve is to press a button in my external browser and close said browser which would bring my app back to front.

Or is there some kind of custom intent library for android which could help me achieve the same result.

Any hint would be appreciated, as my research so far as not been very fruitful.. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement deep-linking.

Comment: Alright, that's the term for it. Thank you I will look into getting it done :)